# WPF Fullscreen taskbar appearence

Tags: c#, wpf, fullscreen

To make fullscreen window I tried this :

```
  WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" Topmost="True"
```

It works correctly, but after some time (maybe few hours) when i do something with window (for example click button) the task bar appear, and it is not hiding. How to make task bar not appear?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<Window ShowTitleBar="False" IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize="True">
```

To use IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize you need to be using MahApps see this: [mahApps](http://mahapps.com/)

Or

```
WindowStyle="None"
ResizeMode="NoResize"
```

and

```
this.Width = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
this.Height = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
this.Left = 0;
this.Top = 0;
this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
```

reference: [WPF fullscreen](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107994/Taskbar-with-Window-Maximized-and-WindowState-to-N)

Good luck!